# Convert console.log into return on script for GTM

Tags: javascript, tags, google-tag-manager

I finally found a script that takes todays date, add 7 days and then outputs it in the format I need to put in GTM. But then I got the error from GTM that it needs a return.

As far as I have been able to find, this means that the Javascript should end with a "return".
For example (random example):
 `return daysOfWeek[time.getDay()];`

The code I have now is:

```
var someDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 7;
var result = someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
console.log(new Date(result).toLocaleDateString('en-CA'));
```

Can somebody explain how to convert this to something with a return at the end? Or perhaps in such a way that GTM accepts it?

As a novice/beginner is tried to simply add something like `return newdate(new Date(result).toLocaleDateString('en-CA'));` but that obviously didn't work. I also tried to add a function at the beginning, but that didn't work either.
In the end I had to throw in the towel because I simply don't understand well enough how this part works.

I tried to edit the script, but my very limited knowledge on this part fails me. I was kinda hoping that it would be a simple case of changing the last part of the code. But that doesn't seem to work.

I am trying to achieve that GTM accepts the script and the output gives me the date 7 days from today, in the format "YYYY-MM-DD".
Right now it is 2023-10-09, so the output would be: 2023-10-16.

Comment: Does `return new Date(result).toLocaleDateString('en-CA');` work? I don't know why you feel you had to wrap everything inside `newdate()`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I ended up with this code after editing a few different scripts and trying to put them together. This was the only way I got it to work.

Comment: You say "but that obviously didn't work". Does that code you shared work or not?

Comment: The code that you see in the grey block works, but isn't accepted by GTM. My comment 2 alinea's below the code refers to the sentence in front of it, where I explain that I tried to add some code in order to get it to work with GTM. The addition that I did "obviously didn't work". ( it broke the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function () {
  var someDate = new Date();
  var numberOfDaysToAdd = 7;
  var result = someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
  return new Date(result).toLocaleDateString("en-CA");
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately GTM gives me the following error: 'Error on line 6, character 3: Parse error. ')' expected'.

Comment: I edited it slightly to get:
```
function () {
  var someDate = new Date();
  var numberOfDaysToAdd = 7;
  var result = someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
  return new Date(result).toLocaleDateString("en-CA");
}
```
And it seems to work now.